# In Chrome Developer tool which one is accurate: Responsive or Dimension:[Number]

Tags: html, css, responsive, developer-tools

### I am trying to build a responsive design,But encounter this problem:

In the chrome developer tool if I set the device screen size to 1440px for example, everything is good:

[image: when I see my site in the fixed dimension everything looks good]

But when I try to see my website in the Responsive way, with the same width and height ( 1440px for example) the design becomes warped.

[image: I used the same width and height but this time with Responsive].

So my question is: if a user with this screen size (1440px for example) see my web page , which one will be shown?

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 includes a handy tool for responsive design called `viewport`.
Try including `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` at the top of your HTML file. This will set the width of the page to the screen-width automatically. For more information on responsive design I recommend W3 School's tutorial. Additionally, I would recommend posting code samples with your question and avoiding the use of pictures when possible.

Comment: thank you for trying to solve the problem. I already added this line :
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> and I have the same problem. the code is some long svg, which is not the main case. the main question is why dev tools show two different things, in responsive and fixed dimension, even though they have the same values.

Comment: Is your website resizing as intended with fixed dimensions?